How to disable form type checking
embedFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  withLogin: [''],
   expiredTime: this.formBuilder.group({
    day: ['', Validators.min(0)],
    hour: ['', Validators.max(24)]
  }),
  embedUrl: ['']
});

then
this.embedFormGroup.get('withLogin').patchValue(1)

TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Is there any way to solve this problem without changing the initial value of the form?
Because there are many such errors in my project

If you want untyped form Controls you could use UntypedFormBuilder instead of FormBuilder
import { UntypedFormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private formBuilder:UntypedFormBuilder){}

embedFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  withLogin: [''],
   expiredTime: this.formBuilder.group({
    day: ['', Validators.min(0)],
    hour: ['', Validators.max(24)]
  }),
  embedUrl: ['']
});


You probably should have specified what platform/language in your post body. Regardless, the only way I can think of is typecasting.
That would look something like: this.embedFormGroup.get('withLogin').patchValue((1).toString())
This will convert the number 1 to a string before patching the value, which should resolve the TypeScript error. Remember, this is just a workaround and might not be the best solution depending on your use case. It’s generally a good practice to ensure that the types of your form controls match the types of the data you’re working with. If withLogin is expected to be a number, it would be better to initialize it as a number. But if you have many such errors in your project and changing all initial values is not feasible, this workaround can help.
